# insert only </div> via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem here, as jQuery seems to be 'too smart'.

In my HTML-code, I want to insert this string into a div-container:

```
</div><div class="something">
```

As you see, first is the closing-tag, second is the opening tag.
That is because I want to cut one big DIV into pieces.

I tried it with jQuery, which I prefer:

```
$(this).children('.abc').each(function(j){
    if( (j+1) % 3 == 0){ 
        $(this).after('</div><div class="abc">');
    }
});
```

I am counting sub-containers and after each three containers I want to cut the parenting container.

Unfortunately jQuery ignores the `</div>` and puts a closing tag to the `<div>`. So the result is `<div class="abc"></div>`.

How do I tell jQuery to insert the string, that I want without any own semi-intelligent parsing?

Comment: You can only insert entire elements when manipulating the DOM. If you want to split a div, you need to create a new one, then transfer the required content from the original to the new one.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to cut one div into two, you may be better off *replacing* one with two rather than trying to be smart and inserting a closing `</div>` and an opening `<div>`.

```js
$('.one').replaceWith('<div class="two">two</div><div class="three">three</div>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">I am one</div>
```

You can, of course, transfer any content to the new div's as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/4nc0raf4/)**

Although what you're doing is logically correct, it is not always preferred in terms of implementation. You have to look around for certain ethos that are defined by library.
In case of `jQuery` that ethos is defined by the `.wrapAll` API.

You can try something like this.

If I understand your question correctly, what you're trying to do is convert

```
<div class="abc">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
</div>
```

Into

```
<div class="abc">
    <div class="something">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="something">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Wrap it like

```
var divs = $("div.abc > div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
    divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='something'></div>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, but just try it like

```
$(this).children('.abc').each(function(j){
    if( (j+1) % 3 == 0){ 
        $(this).after('</div>');
        $(this).after('<div class="abc">');
    }
});
```

or vice versa